# How can I copy files and create path destination folders if they dont exist?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to copy a folder from source to destination.
The destination folder does not always exist.

Which copy command creates the destination folder if it doesn't exist?

Example:

```
$(CP) $(HOME)/text.txt $(DEST)/dir1/dir2/text.txt
```

Folders `dir1` and `dir2` don't always exist and should be created.

Comment: Read the man page for `mkdir`. Pay close attention to the `-p` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What shell are you using?

Regardless, it appears there's no cool shortcut. The best way to go is to simply combine `mkdir` and `cp`. Following your example:

`mkdir -p dir1/dir2 && cp ~/text.txt ~/dir1/dir2`

This command would put test.txt in dir2. Hope this helps!

BTW, the syntax for `cp` is `cp [source] [destination dir]`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of GNU make, there's a neat trick you can use to create the directory for any target more or less automatically:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%/.:
        mkdir -p -- "$*"
```

Now, for each target where you want the destination directory created, you add "| $$(@D)/." as prerequisite:

```
$(TARGET) : $(PREREQUISITES) | $$(@D)/.
        ...
```